# Simulator not showing in Spotlight search - Big Sur

Tags: ios, macos, ios-simulator

Hopefully a straight forward one here, but my Simulator app (Xcode IOS Simulator) is not being found through Spotlight search on Mac. I recently upgraded to Big Sur and I am currently using 11.1.

Just wondering if anyone is having the same problem. I am able to access Simulator through other methods but it just doesn't seem to be indexed in the Spotlight search.
Cheers

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. It did seem to showing up prior to Big Sur as you say. Not sure how to remedy.

Answer (score 59):

The following worked for me on **Big Sur 11.5.2**:

1. Locate and obtain the absolute path to your `Xcode.app`. For me it was `/Applications/Xcode.app/`
2. Since Simulator comes with Xcode, with your terminal, execute `ls /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications` to ensure you see `Simulator.app`
3. What we need to do now is to get Spotlight to index the applications directory in *Step-2*

   - Open finder via your terminal `open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`, you should see an "Applications" directory
   - Open System Preferences >> Spotlight, then select "Privacy Tab"
   - Following the steps from [Apple's Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716)

     - Drag the said "Applications" directory into "Privacy Tab" GUI
     - Remove the said "Applications" directory from the same GUI
     - Quit System Preference
4. Give it a moment then re-launch Spotlight and search for "Simulator"... I hope it shows up for you

Comment: Wow! You saved me a day!

Comment: What a joke that this type of thing happens arbitrarily on a minor update, not even on the Catalina -> Big Sur install. In any case, thanks for saving me the headache!

Comment: That's a really great workaround! Hope this glitch gets fixed in the next update.

Comment: Funny how it actually worked 

Comment: working like charm on macOS Monterey too, thanks a lot

Comment: Still works on macOS Ventura, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

In addion to Jonalogy's answer, you can import a specific app from command line.

```
mdimport /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app
```

Comment: Oh cool this is something new for me, thanks!
Googling `mdimport` led me to this insightful [article](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/01/28/spotlight-on-search-how-spotlight-works/) that shed more light under Spotlight's hood for me.

Comment: Did not work in macOS Ventura. Adding and removing the directory worked.

Answer (score 5):

Also having this issue. I came up with a half-workaround so that it shows up in launchpad at least.

Open the Simulator using Xcode and then when it shows up in the dock, right-click it, hover over *Options*, and then click *Show in Finder*. You'll see the app in a new finder window. Right-click it and select *Make Alias*. Drag and drop this into your applications folder. Now when you open the launchpad, you can search for it there. (5 finger pinch to launch the launchpad)

Comment: Thanks Jenhifer, that will see me through :)